# GROUP BY ORDER BY Help

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

The following code works, but I want the groups to show their latest query by datetime not the first datetime query. I've tried changing around the ORDER BY from ASC/DESC, but that just changes the order of all the groups, not the data within the groups. I need for both all the inside data of the groups and all the groups to order by the latest datetime.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM emails 
        WHERE sentto='$sid' 
        GROUP BY sentto 
        ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT $eu, $limit ";
```

Instead of it showing groups and ordering them by the first query:
Message from Sam Richards on **January 22, 2011** (this is a group)
Message from John Smith on **January 5, 2011** (this is a group)

I want it to show groups and order them by the latest query:
Message from John Smith on **April 19, 2011** (this is a group)
Message from Sam Richards on **March 10, 2011** (this is a group)

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think part of your problem is that you are selecting non-aggregate columns with a group-by query. You should be explicit about which values you want it to return in the aggregate query result.

```
SELECT sentto, MAX(datetime) AS datetime FROM emails
  GROUP BY sentto
  ORDER BY datetime desc LIMIT $eu, $limit;
```

I'm still not sure that this gives you what you want. It sounds like you want to actually retrieve the rows for each individual email and just use the GROUP BY maximum for sorting. To do that, you'd probably need to do the above query, then go back and do a second query for each sentto. I can't think of a way offhand to do it in a single query.

```
SELECT * FROM emails
  WHERE sentto=$sid
  ORDER BY datetime DESC;
```

(For each sentto returned in the first query.)

Comment: This is almost working. I'm tweaking things around trying to figure it out. I almost have it nailed with a single query.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
ORDER BY sentto ASC, datetime DESC
```

Comment: still not showing the latest datetime message for the group main.

Comment: Still didn't work. It orders the groups, but still shows the first item of the groups as the oldest message.

Comment: Yes, re-reading I'm not entirely sure I understand how the data rows you have compare with the desired output (you mention seeing the inside data of groups, but the purpose of group by is to 'collapse' all rows meeting that criteria into a single row, so you can't see the data inside except with aggregate functions such as MAX or SUM).  I think Brian's answer looks like a better bet towards meeting your need though.

Answer (score 0):

To sort the data with in the groups you need to include sentto in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM emails 
            WHERE sentto='$sid' 
            GROUP BY sentto 
            ORDER BY sentto, datetime DESC LIMIT $eu, $limit
```

Comment: Still didn't work. It orders the groups, but still shows the first item of the groups as the oldest message.